# How To Make a Youtube Video in AMP Website Start With Sound

Tags: web, amp-html, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

Im making an AMP website and trying to use Auto-played Youtube video in my website, but the video will play muted from the start unless visitor interact with the video. So how to make it start with sound?

I tried to find the code in the amp.dev documentation but i found no way to make it start not muted

Answer (score 0):

AMP does not support autoplay with sound because it harms the user experience. Also sound will consume data and the battery of mobile devices.